# Can my Azure Cloud costs skyrocket due to DOS attack

Tags: azure

I plan on developing an app for myself on Azure. I plan on using an Web server and a SQL Server. I'll likely just the cheapest versions.

Can my bill skyrocket overnight due to a DOS attack, or some hacking attempts?

Any advice on this top would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends but theoretically yes. 
If you are using auto scaling then it will scale on demand.

But you have few option to protectect from it

1. [Front door](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/frontdoor/)
2. [DDoS protection](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/ddos-protection/)
3. Configure maximum auto scaling options.

Mostly it depends on which services you are using and how you scale

Comment: I'm too green to arrow up, I appreciate your response. Thanks.